# In consistent global states, what is the difference between a run and a consistent run?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I am referring to global states in a distributed system as published in the paper Consistent Global States of Distributed Systems: Fundamental Concepts and Mechanisms by Ozalp Babao and Keith Marzullo ([pdf](https://www.cs.unibo.it/babaoglu/papers/pdf/global-states.pdf)).

On page 7, they define a **run** as follows:

> A **run** of a distributed computation is total ordering that includes all
>   of the events in the global history and that is consistent with each
>   local history.

Then on page 11, they define a **consistent run** as follows:

> A run **R** is said to be consistent if for all events, **e happens before e'** implies that **e** appears
>   before **e'** in **R**. In other words, the total order imposed by **R** on the events
>   is an extension of the partial order defined by causal precedence.

So far so good but then they go on to say in the following sentences there can be be two consistent global states **A** and **B** and they define some sort of **leads-to** operator which says **A leads to B** if there exists some consistent run in which this holds.

My question is, how can there be multiple runs? Won't there be a unique run (a totally ordered relation of events based on some tie breaker for concurrent events) for every system setup? How can there be multiple runs (other than the ones induced by different concurrent event tie breakers)?